# Redirect `foo/` to foo/bar/` from within `foo`

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I have a folder `~/Branches/` that is accessible via apache2 at `localhost/~me/`. Now I have `localhost/~me/branches_index/web/index.php` that I would like to make available at `localhost/~me/branches_index/`

So how can I redirect from `/~me/branches_index/` to `/~me/branches_index/web/` from the `/Branches/branches_index/` folder?

---

I tried, but I did not succeed.

Endless loop:

```
Redirect /~me/branches_index/ /~me/branches_index/web/
```

Put `/web/` at the front:

```
Redirect / /web/
```

Comment: Your question isn't *really* a duplicate of the mod_rewrite question, but you'll find more details on how to do what you want over there :)

Answer (score 2):

The redirect you're attempting is failing because
`Redirect /~me/branches_index/ /~me/branches_index/web/`
will redirect everything from `/~me/branches_index/*` recursively.

That means `/~me/branches_index/what/so/ever` 
will be redirected to `/~me/branches_index/web/what/so/ever` thus you end up in an endless cycle.

The solution is to use rewrite in `.htaccess` file, saved at `/~me/branches_index/`.
Something like this code should do the work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)web/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~me/branches_index/web/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put this in the  or .htaccess configuration for /branches_index/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web/
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [QSA,L]
```